# Authored by lookup

Tags: 7, forms

Right now the when I want to change 'authored by' there is a look up by username. Is there an easy way to change that to enter the users email address?

Answer (score 0):

To change 'authored by'  autocomplete with email, In your form alter change the auto complete path as follows,

```
if ($form_id == 'test_node_form') {    
    $form['author']['name']['#autocomplete_path']= 'user/autocomplete/email';   
 }
```

Originally this path is [#autocomplete_path] = user/autocomplete

In your module define the menu path, hook_menu

```
function example_menu() {  
  $item[] = array(   
  'path' => 'user/autocomplete/email',   
  'callback' => 'example_autocomplete',   
  'access' => user_access('access example autocomplete')  
  ); 
}
```

Define the call back

```
function example_autocomplete($string=''){
  //your query to get email
  //return the output as $mathes
   drupal_json_output($matches);
   exit();
 }
```

Hope this may helps you